# How to read certain rows of a csv file to another csv file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am new here and also in Python scripting but i need some help about my litle script. I have a `CSV` file like this:

```
19928;renet;54;amsterdam

27732;tango;36'rotterdam
```

enz. enz

How can a select only the rows with amsterdam for writing in the new file?

This is my script:

```
import csv
import os

data = [] #Buffer list 
with open(os.path.join("CSV", "verliezen.csv"), "rb") as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        try:
            new_row = [row[0], row[3]]
            data.append(new_row)

        except IndexError as e:
            print e
            pass

        with open("the_new_csv.csv", "w+") as to_file:
            writer = csv.writer(to_file, delimiter=";")
            for new_row in data:
                writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: can someone dupe-hammer that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the last position in your row is equal 'amsterdam', like int he code below:

```
import csv

data = [] #Buffer list 
with open("CSV\\verliezen.csv", "rb") as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        if row[-1] == 'amsterdam':
            data.append(row)

with open("the_new_csv.csv", "w+") as to_file:
    writer = csv.writer(to_file, delimiter=";")
    for new_row in data:
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect